# keep getting ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED exception when calling PassengerDetailsRQ

Tags: c#, api, soap, air, sabre

I am using Sabre SOAP Api in C#. I got the response from session creation successfully, I added wsdl Service Reference
http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/ServicesPlatform/PassengerDetails3.3.0RQ.wsdl to my test project and pass required values to parameters in the request as given in the documentation https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Passenger_Details.

this is my xml to that is send to sabre and Getting Exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.2.1" 
    IgnoreOnError="false">
  <MiscSegmentSellRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
    <MiscSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-01-10T16:45" InsertAfter="0" NumberInParty="1" Status="HK" Type="OTH">
      <OriginLocation LocationCode="SAN" />
      <Text>America Tours</Text>
      <VendorPrefs>
        <Airline Code="DL" />
      </VendorPrefs>
    </MiscSegment>
  </MiscSegmentSellRQ>
  <PostProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
    <EndTransactionRQ>
      <EndTransaction Ind="true">
        <Email Ind="true" />
      </EndTransaction>
      <Source ReceivedFrom="SWS TESTING" />
    </EndTransactionRQ>
  </PostProcessing>
  <PreProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2" />
  <PriceQuoteInfo xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
    <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" />
  </PriceQuoteInfo>
  <SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
    <SpecialServiceRQ>
      <SpecialServiceInfo>
        <SecureFlight>
          <PersonName DateOfBirth="02/02/1998" NameNumber="1.1">
            <GivenName>Usama QW</GivenName>
            <Surname>Alam</Surname>
          </PersonName>
          <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline />
          </VendorPrefs>
        </SecureFlight>
      </SpecialServiceInfo>
    </SpecialServiceRQ>
  </SpecialReqDetails>
  <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
    <AgencyInfo>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>America Tours</AddressLine>
        <CityName>Los Angeles</CityName>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
        <PostalCode>90020</PostalCode>
        <StateCountyProv StateCode="CA" />
        <StreetNmbr>3434 West 6th Street Suite 400-6</StreetNmbr>
      </Address>
      <Ticketing TicketType="7T-A" />
    </AgencyInfo>
    <CustomerInfo>
      <ContactNumbers>
        <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="213-738-8185" PhoneUseType="A" />
        <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="3162881034" PhoneUseType="A" />
      </ContactNumbers>
      <Email Address="www.usamaalam60@gmail.com" ShortText="AmericaTours" />
      <Email Address="admin@koreaonly.com" ShortText="AmericaTours" />
      <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" NameReference="MR" PassengerType="ADT">
        <GivenName>Usama sd</GivenName>
        <Surname>Alam</Surname>
      </PersonName>
    </CustomerInfo>
  </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this one you seem to be using invalid service version for the 3.2 namespace. Try with something like this:

```
*xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2"* and *version="3.2.0"*.
```

You were using version 2.2.1 here which will require a different URL.

Are you intending to use `3.2.0` version? I can see that the dates are not valid as per the schema as well. You have:

```
*DateOfBirth="02/02/1998"*
```

but should have:

```
*DateOfBirth="1998-02-02"*
```